# how to add checkbox element to a combobox dynamically

Tags: jquery

I want to add checkbox element to a combo box / select element dynamically. I tried with this

```
    var option="";
    for (i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
        option = option + '<option><input type="checkbox" name="myCheckbox" value="checkbox" /></option>';
    }
    $('#cmbRebateCategories1').append(option);
```

This is the HTML markup I have,

```
        <select id="cmbRebateCategories1">
        </select>
```

but its not working. Please help me out.

Comment: `option` tag must have `text` body, not `html` body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not something that the `<option>` element supports. You'd have to roll your own select replacement.

[jQuery UI MultiSelect Widget](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/) appears to be doing what you're requesting.

Comment: Is it possible that if we dynamically add the select element and then add the options having input element dynamically in it. Will it work in that manner ?

Comment: @Bibhu: no, no matter how and when you add it, a select box is not designed to contain anything but text. You would have to do something entirely different, similar to what the people who made [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/) are doing, only they're not specifically targeting your requirement. I'm sure there are other plugins that are, tho.

Comment: Thanks David. Really appreciate your help. But I have tried this one and also a couple of others but having conflicts with other already implemented jquery plugins, so wanted to code this instead of using any plugin.